# Cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can we prove that cardinality of set of all real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equal for every $n$ in the set of all natural numbers?

Comment: Yes we can, there are many bijections. Most notably you can show that $\mathbb R^n$ is obtained by taking limit points of the countable set $\mathbb Q^n$

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the same cardinality, you could continue on by induction.

Comment: @AlexR Can you please explain a little bit more what you mean by limit points?

Comment: @Sarah.N Well, the definition of a limit point is a point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if there exists a sequence $(x_n) \subset A$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider z=(x,y) with x=0.x1x2x3… and y=0.y1y2y3… their decimal expansions (the standard ones without an infinite series of nines as a suffix). Then the number f(x,y)=0.x1y1x2y2x3y3… is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1) \times (0,1)$. Since $card(0,1)=card(\mathbb{R})$ we have  $card(\mathbb{R}) = card(\mathbb{R^2})$. 
The rest is done by simple induction:

$card(\mathbb{R^n})=card(\mathbb{R^{n-1}} \times \mathbb{R})=card(\mathbb{R^{n-1}}) + card(\mathbb{R})=card(\mathbb{R}) + card(\mathbb{R})= card(\mathbb{R^{2}})=card(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Hmm.  $f$ looks more like an *injection* from $[0,1)\times[0, 1)$ to $[0, 1)$.  It's not even surjective onto that interval: for example, $0.90909090909...$ is not in the image.  There's some work needed to get from here to a bijection.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You were right, I fixed most of it

Comment: @Kaligule How did you say the last line?

Comment: @Sarah.N It is [induktion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). You assume that for a fix $n$ you know that $card(\mathbb{R}^{n-1}) = card(\mathbb{R})$. Then you use that to prove $card(\mathbb{R}{n}) = card(\mathbb{R})$. And so on...

Comment: @Kaligule I mean the part that you said $|R^{n-1} * R| = |R^{n-1}|+|R|$

Answer (score 2):

for any $m,n \gt 0$ look at the half-open open unit hypercubes. represent the reals in (say) binary notation, avoiding infinite sequences of 1's. then you can set up a 1-1 correspondence between the points of the hypercubes in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbb{R^m}$ by interleaving the digits of $(r_1,r_2,...,r_n)$. clearly this is reversible.

since the set of such hypercubes in any $\mathbb{R^n}$ are countable, this bijection can be extended to include the whole spaces.