# One-to-one mapping from $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ to $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: probability, matrices

According to the Lebesgue measure theory, we can prove that $P\{A \in G{L_n}(\mathbb{R})\}=1, A \in {M_n}(\mathbb{R})$.
I would like to define the probability that a matrix $A$ is reversible:
$$P\{A\in G{L_n}(R)\}=\frac{{|G{L_n}(\mathbb{R})|}}{{|{M_n}(\mathbb{R})|}},$$
We have proved that $P\{A \in G{L_n}(\mathbb{R})\}=1, A \in {M_n}(\mathbb{R})$, then $|G{L_n}(\mathbb{R})|=|{M_n}(\mathbb{R})|$.

But now I'm having trouble showing there exists an one-to-one mapping from $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ to $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Of course, these sets have the same cardinality, which is the cardinality of $\Bbb R$. So there will be a one to one (and even bijective) function in either direction, though this function will not necessarily be continuous.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry,I don't konw how to show that they both have the same cardinal as $R$.It seems that this proof is not simple.Could you please write the proof?Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @HIG4399 It suffices to note that, for any integer $n \geq 1$, $\Bbb R$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R^n$, as is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/966645/81360) and in the associated linked questions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh!!!I forget such an important property. I think I can prove it by constructing a subset of $GL_{n}(R)$.Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'm interested to know, how do you define division of infinite cardinals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both have the same cardinal as $\mathbb R$ and therefere there is even a bijection between them.

Comment: Can we find the specific form $f$ of the bijection.For example,$f(A)=B,A \in {M_n}(R),B \in G{L_n}(R).$

Comment: @HlG4399 I suppose so, but this would be a bit hard.

Comment: Sorry,and I don't konw how to show that they both have the same cardinal as $R$.Could you please write the proof?Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I think that there are some differences between the measure and the cardinal.

Comment: Absolutely. Perhaps you should write a seperate question about the latter issue. Think for instance about the intervals $(0, 1)$ and $(0, 2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. They have the same cardinality, the bijection is multiplication/division by 2. However the measure of $(0, 2)$ is 2 and that of $(0, 1)$ is 1, as it should be. So different measures can come with the same cardinality. The opposite (same measure, different cardinality) can also happen but only in the special case that this same measure equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

Approaching probability with cardinality only works for finite sets (or more generally, discrete measures).

Consider this: $\mathbb N$ and $2\mathbb N$ have the same cardinality but that does not imply that the probability of selecting an even number at random is $1$, instead of the expected answer $1/2$. See [Natural density at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).

The reason that $P\{A \in G{L_n}(\mathbb{R})\}=1$ is that the complement of $G{L_n}(\mathbb{R})$ has Lebesgue measure zero, being the zero set of the determinant function.